# Suggestions for Software Testing Blogs

Tags: test-design

I want to be more up to date with current events and ideas in SQA. I was wondering if anyone could offer any suggestions for Software Testing Blogs.

Comment: welcome to SQA.  Please take the time to search the site a bit.  This question has been asked a number of times.  It also is one that can be answered by doing the same search in your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

[James Bach's Blog](http://satisfice.com/blog/)

[Pradeep's Blog](http://testertested.blogspot.in/)

these are my favorites, but there are plenty out there which will be useful. Google is your best friend.

Answer (score 0):

On the "Agile Testing" scene, you might like:

- http://gojko.net/
- http://www.shino.de/blog/
- http://lisacrispin.com/
- http://janetgregory.ca/blog/

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a list of relevant blogs on my own "All Things Quality" blog:

Here's a list of blogs:

http://www.allthingsquality.com/p/people-in-testing.html

And here's a list of recent posts from some of those blogs:

http://strazzerej.blogspot.com/2011/12/blog-post.html